# How to show loading of table whenever List filter changes in React Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, react-admin

**Is there any way to get the loading or fetching state of Data provider in react admin?**
**So that we can show shimmer or loader on tables till the data fetching is done.**

**I have tried to get using useContextList() hook inside MyActions component but it don't trigger. Sometimes it show or not.**

```
 <List
            {...props}
            title="Data"
            exporter={false}
            filter={filter}
            empty={false}
            actions={<MyActions filter={filter} />}
>
    <Datagrid>
     <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
     <TextField source="age" label="Age" />
     <TextField source="gender" label="Gender" />
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[useListContext()](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useListContext.html) is callable in List child and all its chidlren.

In the following example a loading (react-admin `<Loading/>`) is display when the List is fetching or loading:

```
const MyList = () => {
<List
    {...props}
    title="Data"
    exporter={false}
    filter={filter}
    empty={false}
    actions={<MyActions filter={filter} />}
>
    <MyDatagrid/>
</List>
}

const MyDatagrid = () => {
    const {data, isLoading, isFetching} = useListContext()

    if (isLoading || isFetching) {
        return <Loading />
    }

    return (
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
            <TextField source="age" label="Age" />
            <TextField source="gender" label="Gender" />
        </Datagrid>
    )

}
```